# Pyside6-uic Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using

Tags: python, environment-variables, pyside6, uic

I install Python on my company computer, also I want to install the Pyside6 module but I can't use the "pip install pyside6" command to install it because our company computer has a setting firewall and I have no authority to request it.

so I use my laptop to install the Pyside6 module in advance, then copy the module to  the python file, but when I want to use the "pyside6-uic" command to convert file.ui to file.py, it shows this error :

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ccaR.jpg)

owing to authority, I can't use the environment variable setting, but I used CMD to get my company the environment variable

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bIWG.jpg)

it looks like no mistake, but I found when I use the "pyside6-uic" command,  it uses the path of Python on my laptop, how can I change the path to my company computer's python.exe path

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZVA6.jpg)

can I find out files in the pyside6 module to change the python.exe path when I use the "pyside6-uic" command?

It show error:

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\UUC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"  "C:\Users\F52655\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pyside6-uic.exe" test.ui ': ???????????

I want change the "C:\Users\UUC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" to "C:\Users\F52655\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"

Comment: If your only issue is the network access, then just download the required packages and manually install them from those binaries.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried to download the pyside6 who package and manually download it, But it always show "Time out"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you could actually do this. Because it is an executable file `.exe`, means that it is already compiled.

But, you can try to install Python using Chocolatey or another package manager (if possible) available on Windows. After you need to install this package using the pip that is installed for that Python version.